# vscode text editor settings - manually configure language list

Tags: configuration, editor, visual-studio-code

I would like to auto-close brackets for `.csv` files when they are open in `vscode`. Given the following user settings...

```
{
    "editor.autoSurround": "languageDefined"
    ...
    "editor.autoClosingQuotes": "languageDefined"
}
```

... is there a user configuration where I can add or remove language modes to apply the `autoClosingQuotes` setting(s) to *without* enabling it for *all* language modes?

Answer (score 1):

What you want are called "language-specific settings". See [using language-specific settings in vscode](https://flaviocopes.com/vscode-language-specific-settings/) and [documentation for same](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_language-specific-editor-settings).

In your case:

```
"editor.autoClosingBrackets": "never",

"[plaintext]": {
  "editor.autoClosingQuotes": "languageDefined"
}
```

You can play with those settings to achieve what you want. First I set all languages to `never`, and then enable it only for `plaintext`.

Why did I use `[plaintext]` above? Because in looking through the choices (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> and search for "configure language-specific settings" there isn't a `.csv` choice.  I assume plain text is as close as you are going to get.

Comment: frustratingly, a few flavors of the `csv` language mode are available when _setting_ the language via `ctrl+k, m`, but I haven't yet found an enumeration of the actual key value to configure settings for those language modes (or, better still, an exhaustive list of available language modes and their keys).